# Can’t stop rotation of object with thingiview

Tags: javascript, stl

I am using the very basic example of thigiview.js visible here [tbuser/thingiview.js](https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js?files=1) to view an .stl file.
The example works and it correctly displays a rotating cube.

[image: rotating cube]

```
<script src="javascripts/Three.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/plane.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/thingiview.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {

    thingiurlbase = "/thingiview/javascripts";
    thingiview = new Thingiview("viewer");
    thingiview.setObjectColor('#C0D8F0');
    thingiview.setObjectMaterial('solid');
    thingiview.setShowPlane(false);
    thingiview.setRotation(false);   
    thingiview.initScene();
    thingiview.loadSTL("/thingiview/objects/cube.stl");

  }
</script>


<div id="viewer" style="width:300px;height:300px" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

Options such as *setObjectMaterial* and *setShowPlane* also work well.

All I want form thigiview is just to represent a .stl as a still images but the option

```
thingiview.setRotation(false);
```

doesn’t work and I dont get any js error.

Comment: I download library and had a try. I have same problem with example, rotation cannot be stop after been enable twice...

Comment: @Camille Dell'Ava thx for trying to help. You could maybe vote for the post to bring more views on the problem.